# Assign information to element in array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Is it possible to assign information to an element in an array in java?
For example, can I have an element containing a title and a number etc?
How do you go about this? thanks

Comment: Have you learned about classes yet?

Comment: An array list may not be the appropriate data structure for your needs. If you want to assign numbers to a title, a dictionary like a `HashTable` is probably the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, instead of having an array of primitive types (like ints) or Strings, define your own class and then create an array of that. Then you can have whatever information you want in there.

Alternatively, if the array *must* be an array of primitives or Strings because some other method requires it to be in that form, you could either create a second array like that on demand, or use a second array for the associated data (again you might create your own class for this).